# How to split meshes created with the array modifier?

Tags: modifiers

How to split meshes created with the array modifier? It didn't split them in Edit mode with <kbd>P</kbd> -> *By Loose Parts*.

Comment: Probably you didn't apply the Array modifier.

Comment: I took a cube ... added the modifier array ... created 3 cubic .... now I want to have individual objects .... I go in edit mode ... p -> By loose parts but does not work..J tried in every way ... thanks

Comment: hit the apply button of the array modifiers